# How to develop on GoogleSignIn with Google Play App Signing enabled

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I am working on a mobile app, it hasn't been released yet. The Google Play App Signing is already set up as "is enabled for this app", which means that Google signs it with a key only they have, once you upload it to the store.

Specifically I'm working on GoogleSignIn, and am up against the error code 12500 "A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred", which I suspect is due to key mismatch.

If I build the app from my desktop and install it onto my phone, it's signed a key we have locally. I've put the SHA-1 fingerprint of that key into the Google API console under "Credentials" / "OAuth 2.0 clientIDs" for the mobile client.

But I suspect that since Google Play is expecting to see apps signed with its own key, that's why it's rejecting sign-ins from an app signed with *our* key. Of course, we don't have the private key half of what the Google Play store has, that's the whole point.

So how is that ever supposed to work? How can I test the functionality on an app signed with our key if Google expects it to be signed with the Play Store key?

Or am I just misunderstanding the whole thing?

Comment: Related section: [New Apps: Step 4: Register your app signing key with API providers](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en)